# Get how many instances of a 'field' are in a text, and append each value with the same 'field' to the same variable

Tags: javascript, email

So lets say I have a mailto email in which a checkbox question exists that asks the user to pick the best fruits out of a list of fruits (check all that apply.) They end up with apples, bananas, and pears. The mailto email that they trigger then contains the following (assuming the checkboxes in the question are named bestFruits):

```
...
bestFruits=apples
bestFruits=bananas
bestFruits=pears
...
```

So in my javascript file, I have the following line to parse values from the email:

```
var bestFruits = mail.bodyText.match(/bestFruits=\s*(\S.*\S)\s*/);
```

So my issue is that this would (presumably) take only one value by the end. What I need, is for the javascript to loop and add each value of bestFruits in the email to the bestFruits var so that each value (apples, bananas, and pears) are all in the bestFruits var.

Is there any way to do this? I tried making a for loop, but I couldn't determine the syntax to loop through the mailto email body and add each instance of bestFruits to the variable.

I'm still extremely new to all this, as I was thrust in recently. If I'm missing something fundamental, I'd appreciate a quick pointing-out. If you require any more info, I'd be happy to try to provide it.

Thanks for reading guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need looping. You do need to match all the fruits (as per your example, matching all single words after `bestFruits`), remove `bestFruits=` from the matches, join the resulting array and store it in a variable. Like this:

```
var bestFruits = mail.bodyText.match(/bestFruits=\w+/g)
                              .map(function(x){return x.split('=')[1]})
                              .join(',');
```

What does it do:

1. Matches all your best fruits.
2. Takes each `bestFruits=abc` element and replaces it with `abc` (i.e., splits with `=` separator and takes the second part)
3. Makes the string of your fruits (converts the resulting array to string with `,` joiner).

Comment: Since there is a capturing group `(\S.*\S)` shouldn't there be a way to get just the captures and avoid the split on `=`?

Comment: @Stephen Sounds legit, but I couldn't find a good way to get the matched group without using replace, hence removing it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close - modified your regex a little bit:

```
var body = `this=is
an=example
bestFruits=apples
bestFruits=bananas
bestFruits=pears
of=doing
things=ok?
`;

var re = /bestFruits=(.*)/g;
var fruitMatches = body.match(re);
var bestFruits = fruitMatches.map(function(fruitMatch) {
  return fruitMatch.split('=')[1];
});

console.log(bestFruits); // ["apples", "bananas", "pears"]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariocatch/vztp8573/)

Comment: OP did not state whether each _bestFruits=x_ will be alone on a line. This is great if so, but will fail if not. Consider a line like `bestFruits=apples bestFruits=peaches` which is, I think, why the OP uses `\S`

Comment: Within the email, each bestFruits=x will be on their own individual lines.

Comment: Great :) In that case either of the provided answers should suffice.